# Delphi - Quick Report(Dynamic report preview)

Tags: delphi

I am creating run time report(Quick report).
1. Create QRSubdetails band.
Assign parent, master and dataset.
2. Create one RQ label
assign parent
3. Create QRDbText
assign dataset and datafield and parent field
4 Write Select statement and open query.(select name from Member)
assign to column name to TQRDBText .datafield:='name';

Problem -  In report first row is printing 'Name' instead of actual data from table. Rest of record is print properly except first row data. Could anybody help me what are property I am missing ?

Comment: What is your Delphi version? Thanks.

Comment: I am using XE7 .